# Retrieve hours and minutes with meridiem indicator (am/pm) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have hours and minutes in different columns like below

| Hour of Day | Minute of Day |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 50 |
| 15 | 00 |

By using these values I need the exact day time like the result of above table should be

| Expected Result |
| --- |
| 10:50 AM |
| 03:00 PM |

How can I achieve this by using Oracle or SQL? Can someone please help me onto this.

Comment: You need something like add hour and add minute to zero time. Similar question is like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510033/oracle-add-1-hour-in-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option - first create a `DATE` value (concatenate hours and minutes, apply appropriate format model); for the final result, apply `TO_CHAR` to it, again with desired format.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (hour, minute) as
  2    (select '10', '50' from dual union all
  3     select '15', '00' from dual
  4    )
  5  select hour, minute,
  6            to_date(hour||':'|| minute, 'hh24:mi') date_value,
  7    to_char(to_date(hour||':'|| minute, 'hh24:mi'), 'hh:mi am') result
  8  from test;

HO MI DATE_VALUE          RESULT
-- -- ------------------- ------------------------------
10 50 01.03.2022 10:50:00 10:50 AM
15 00 01.03.2022 15:00:00 03:00 PM

SQL>
```