# How to add timestaps columns numeric columns as an hour

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to following table called `my_table`.

```
| date                     |numeric_data| new_date
|: -------- |: --------------:|:
| 2019-04-16 00:00:00.0    | 11         |2019-04-16 11:00:00.0 
| 2019-04-15 00:00:00.0    | 13         |2019-04-16 13:00:00.0
```

```
select date+ interval to_char(numeric_data) hour from my_table
```

but it does not works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle Add 1 hour in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510033/oracle-add-1-hour-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NUMTODSINTERVAL` function:

```sql
SELECT date_column + NUMTODSINTERVAL(numeric_data, 'HOUR') AS new_date
FROM   my_table
```

or you can add a multiple of `INTERVAL '1' HOUR`:

```sql
SELECT date_column + numeric_data * INTERVAL '1' HOUR AS new_date
FROM   my_table
```

or you can add fractions of days:

```sql
SELECT date_column + numeric_data/24 AS new_date
FROM   my_table
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table ( date_column, numeric_data ) AS
SELECT DATE '2019-04-16', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-04-15', 13 FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

| NEW_DATE |
| --- |
| 2019-04-16T11:00:00 |
| 2019-04-15T13:00:00 |

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8ac2/1)

Comment: I am using the second approach, but there is no addition in first columns. Actually date_column is timestap without time zone, is it the problem?

Comment: @Mariam The first or second queries will both work for `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE` data types; the third only works for `DATE`s.